# How to print the sum of values from the same objects of 2 parameter in array

Tags: java

I am learning java and I hit into a snag as I could not figure out my loop or array.
I have an array which contains class objects containing a string and integer parameters, in my code, it will be name and dollars.

I am trying to print out the array in which, if there is a same name, it is to print once and with the sum of the dollars (from the same name).

In my `Dollars.java`

```
public class Dollars
{
    private String name;
    private int dollars;
    
    public dollars (String name, int dollars)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.dollars = dollars;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    
    public int getChange()
    {
        return dollars;
    }
}
```

In my main file/ `TestDollars.java`

```
public class TestDollars 
{
    
    public static void displayArray(Dollars[] dol)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int n=0; n<dol.length; n++)
        {
            for (int m=n+1; m<dol.length; m++)
            {
                if (dol[n].getName().equals(dol[m].getName()))
                {
//                    System.out.printf("%s -- %d\n", dol[n].getName(), dol[n].getChange());
                    sum = dol[n].getChange() + dol[m].getChange();
                    System.out.printf("%s -- %d\n", dol[m].getName(), sum);
                    break;
                }
                
            }
            System.out.printf("%s -- %d\n", dol[n].getName(), dol[n].getChange());     
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Test with 5 records
        Dollars[] dollarsArr = new Dollars[5];
        dollarsArr[0] = new Dollars("john", 10);
        dollarsArr[1] = new Dollars("peter", 12);
        dollarsArr[2] = new Dollars("sam", 5);
        dollarsArr[3] = new Dollars("alvin", 16);
        dollarsArr[4] = new Dollars("peter", 30);
        displayArray(dollarsArr);
    }
}
```

Irregardless where I place my print statement in the `displayArray`, the record 'peter' will gets printed twice.

Expected output:

```
john -- 10
peter -- 42
sam -- 5
alvin -- 16
```

Current output:

```
john -- 10
peter -- 42
peter -- 12
sam -- 5
alvin -- 16
peter -- 30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While navigating the array, assign the `change` of each non-null array-element to a variable e.g. `sum` and then add the `change` of the succeeding duplicate elements to it. Make sure to assign `null` to the indices where duplicate elements are found so that they can not be counted again. It also means that you will have to perform a `null` check before performing any operation on the array elements. Print the value of `sum` once you have checked the complete array for duplicate elements.

```
public static void displayArray(Dollars[] dol) {
    for (int n = 0; n < dol.length; n++) {
        if (dol[n] != null) {
            int sum = dol[n].getChange();
            for (int m = n + 1; m < dol.length; m++) {
                if (dol[m] != null && dol[n].getName().equals(dol[m].getName())) {
                    sum += dol[m].getChange();
                    dol[m] = null;
                }
            }
            System.out.printf("%s -- %d\n", dol[n].getName(), sum);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
john -- 10
peter -- 42
sam -- 5
alvin -- 16
```

**Note:** If you want to keep the original array intact, pass the clone of the array to the method, `displayArray` instead of passing the array itself as shown below:

```
displayArray(dollarsArr.clone());
```

Answer (score 4):

You want to group your list by name, please use JAVA 8+ API Stream and the collector group by

```java
public static void displayArray(Dollars[] dol)
    {
       Stream.of(dol)
               // Group by name
               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Dollars::getName))
                .entrySet().stream()
               // Collect a map name and calculate the sum
               .collect(
                    Collectors.toMap(x -> {
                    int total= x.getValue().stream().mapToInt(Dollars::getChange).sum();
                    return new Dollars(x.getKey(),total);
                }, Map.Entry::getValue))
               // Print
               .forEach((dollarsTotal, vals) -> {
                    System.out.println(dollarsTotal.getName()+ " -- "+ dollarsTotal.getChange());
                    // Bonus : Display transactions :
                    for(Dollars transaction : vals)
                    {
                        System.out.println(" \t "+transaction.getName() + " add  -- " + transaction.getChange());
                    }
       });
    }
```

If you want only the values you can collect the keyset

```java
Set<Dollars> groupedByName = Stream.of(dol)
               // Group by name
               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Dollars::getName))
                .entrySet().stream()
               // Collect a map name and calculate the sum
               .collect(
                        Collectors.toMap(x -> {

                    int total= x.getValue().stream().mapToInt(Dollars::getChange).sum();
                    return new Dollars(x.getKey(),total);
                }, Map.Entry::getValue)).keySet();
```

Answer (score 3):

The other answer guides you on fixing your code (Buy they require more work to avoid double counting).

You can reduce the time complexity from O(n<sup>2</sup>) to `O(n)` (and make it simpler) by having a data structure (like a map) to aggregate the result.

Let us create a `Map<String, Integer>` to map a name to the total dollars for that name.

```
Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < dol.length; i++) {
    if (!result.containsKey(dol[i].getName())) { //first time you encounter a name
        result.put(dol[i].getName(), dol[i].getChange());
    } else {
         //add the current change to the already existing sum
         int sumSoFar= result.get(dol[i].getName());
         result.put(dol[i].getName(), sumSoFar + dol[i].getChange());
    }
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Result is,

```
{peter=42, alvin=16, john=10, sam=5}
```

You can simplify the above code using Map's `merge` method as:

```
for (Dollars dollars : dol) {
    result.merge(dollars.getName(), dollars.getChange(), Integer::sum);
}
```

The third argument is a `BiFunction` which sums up the old value and new value (the sum accumulated so far and the current change value). When written as a lambda expression, `Integer::sum` can be written as `(sumSoFar, currentChange) -> sumSoFar + currentChange`.

---

A stream evangelist way would be to use `Collectors.groupingBy` and `Collectors.summingInt`.

```
Arrays.stream(dol)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Dollars::getName, Collectors.summingInt(Dollars::getChange)));
```

Comment: I guess the question is if OP can hand in this in as the answer to their homework assignment?